# How can I separate an ajax call to submit to mutliple db entries based on multiple select

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form that allows a client the ability to select multiple technicians that should receive information that they will then ask a customer when performing a service.

We have a modal that allows a dispatcher the ability to add a new question and assign it to any technicians(one or multiple).  When we AJAX the submission from the modal it processes the information but whenever multiple technicians are selected, it breaks.

The db saves the tech ID as a VARCHAR and will add commas if multiple technicians are selected(1, 3, 5 for example)

Each question should get saved as a new entry in the db separating the tech id's which would require some sort of parsing loop in the ajax call to dynamically create new entries based on the number of technicians selected per question.  The db table is linked so the so-called primary key(id/question id) is not a factor.  How would I process the ajax call in a way to submit different entries based on how many technicians have been selected?

Here is the current code:

```
this.saveQuestion = function (form) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                tempInstance.questions = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(tempInstance.questions);
                tempInstance.loadQuestionsTemplate(tempInstance.questions);
                $('.modal-backdrop').fadeOut();
                setTimeout( function() {
                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                }, 400);
                return false;
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the correct way to save this data is to use a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) to associate questions with technicians. This allows you to look up which questions are assigned to a given technician, not just which technicians are dealing with a given question.

Comment: Thanks @Mikkel.  We thought we needed to do something like that but figured that it would then create duplicate questions within the view and then if we wanted to edit them, it would only edit one at a time instead of the array of values.

Comment: You should have three tables: a questions table, a technicians table, and a junction table that contains only `question_id` and `technician_id` (and a primary key). There is no duplication of data.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine that this was in fact saving correctly to the db but the db call was broken within the actual view that was trying to display the question.